# Filter object ListCollectionView using object's nested SerializedDictonary in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I would like to filter ListCollectionView using SerializableDictionary which is nested in objects.
The filter will check values for the specified (hardcoded) key.

Object (only pseudocode to avoid too much code):

```
MasterRecord{
   MasterName string,
   AdditionalAttributes SerializableDictionary
   }
```

Below is my current simple filter using MasterName(string):

```
    public string Filter
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Filter;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != m_Filter)
            {
                m_Filter = value;

                ListCollectionView masterRecords = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MasterRecordCollection);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_Filter))
                {
                    masterRecords.Filter = (item) => { return (item as MasterRecord).MasterName.StartsWith(m_Filter) ? true : false; };

                }
                else
                    masterRecords.Filter = null;

                masterRecords.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

Sample:

[image: sample data]

How to modyfi my current method and filter by Value (using .Filter() and .StartWith(), for exmaple 'COCA-COLA') AdditionalAttributes(SerializableDictionary) when (this part should be hardcoded) Key == 'c_ProductName' ?

Comment: Use ANY : var results = masterRecords.Where(x => x.AdditionalAttributes.Any(y => (y.Key == "c_ProductName") && (y.Value == "COCA COLA"))).ToList();

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use Filter() and StartWith(). This is part of the dynamic searchbox.

Comment: What has to have StartWith?  My code can be put into a filter.  Do you want one item returned (Then change ToList() to FirstOrDefault)) or multiple items returned?

Comment: I modify your code and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (thanks to @jdweng):

```
masterRecords.Filter = (item) => { return (item as MasterRecord).AdditionalAttributes.Any(y => (y.Key == "c_ProductName") && (y.Value.StartsWith(m_Filter)));};
```

Comment: You do not need ? true : false since ANY already does that.

Comment: you are right. edited answer